# Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed

Tags: java

So, I'm getting the error in the title while executing the below process and I really don't know what can be wrong.

What I'm doing is trying to bring some data from a database to create an object and fill and arraylist with several of it's objects, if not found should throw an exceptio

```
public ArrayList<Caso> buscarCasosPorJuez(String cedula) throws java.sql.SQLException,Exception{
    java.sql.ResultSet rs;
    String sql;
    Caso caso;
    ArrayList<Caso> casos = new ArrayList();
    sql="SELECT * "+
    "FROM tcaso "+
    "WHERE CedulaJ='"+cedula+"';";
    Conector.getConector().ejecutarSQL(sql);
    rs = Conector.getConector().ejecutarSQL(sql,true);

    while (rs.next()){
        caso = new Caso(
            rs.getInt("NumCaso"),
            rs.getString("DescripcionCaso"),
            rs.getString("EstadoCaso"),
            rs.getDate("FechaCreacion").toLocalDate(),
            persona.buscarJuezPorCedula(rs.getString("CedulaJ")),
            persona.buscarQuerellante(rs.getString("CedulaQ"))
            );
        casos.add(caso);
    }

    rs.close();
    return casos;
}
```

Below are the two methods the "New Caso" is calling on the two final lines.

```
public Juez buscarJuezPorCedula(String cedula) throws java.sql.SQLException,Exception{
    Juez juez = null;
    java.sql.ResultSet rs;
    String sql;
    sql = "SELECT Sala,Usuario,Clave,NombreJ,ApellidosJ,TelefonoJ,CedulaJ "+
    "FROM tjuez "+
    "WHERE CedulaJ='"+cedula+"';";
    rs = Conector.getConector().ejecutarSQL(sql,false);

    if (rs.next()){
        juez = new Juez(
            rs.getInt("Sala"),
            rs.getString("Usuario"),
            rs.getString("Clave"),
            rs.getString("NombreJ"),
            rs.getString("ApellidosJ"),
            rs.getString("TelefonoJ"),
            rs.getString("CedulaJ"));
    } else {
        throw new Exception ("Persona no encontrada intentelo de nuevo.");
        }

    rs.close();
    return juez;
}

public Querellante buscarQuerellante(String cedula) throws java.sql.SQLException,Exception{
    Querellante querellante = null;
    java.sql.ResultSet rs;
    String sql;
    sql = "SELECT DireccionQ,NombreQ,ApellidosQ,TelefonoQ,CedulaQ "+
    "FROM tquerellante "+
    "WHERE CedulaQ='"+cedula+"';";
    rs = Conector.getConector().ejecutarSQL(sql,true);

    if (rs.next()){
        querellante = new Querellante(
            rs.getString("DireccionQ"),
            rs.getString("NombreQ"),
            rs.getString("ApellidosQ"),
            rs.getString("TelefonoQ"),
            rs.getString("CedulaQ"));
    } else {
        throw new Exception ("Persona no encontrada intentelo de nuevo.");
    }

    rs.close();
    return querellante;
}
```

Thanks for all the help you can provide.

Comment: The Exception should tell you the statement that caused the problem, so you should know what block of code to debug.

Comment: This code will cause resource leaks but i don't see how it would cause the given exception, maybe it's something in the ejutarsql method? Show more code and a stacktrace.

Comment: Tell us the line where the exception happens and show us the code for the methods called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you are closing the `Statement` object in `ejucutarSQL()`, which closes all `ResultSets` derived from it.

You can't actually *write* all-purpose SQL-executing methods like that, at least not without using `CachedRowSet`, which costs memory.

You need to restructure this code along more conventional lines, with explicit `Connector` and `Statement` objects as local variables so you can close them in reverse order of acquisition.

You should be using `PreparedStatements` instead of building arguments into SQL strings. If you throw an exception you are also leaking the result set.

For example:

```
public Querellante buscarQuerellante(String cedula) throws java.sql.SQLException,Exception{
    String sql = "SELECT DireccionQ,NombreQ,ApellidosQ,TelefonoQ,CedulaQ "+
        "FROM tquerellante "+
        "WHERE CedulaQ=?";
    try (Connnector conn = ...; // TODO
        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        )
    {
        ps.setObject(1, cedula);
        try (ResultSet rs = ps.execute())
        {
            if (rs.next()){
                return new Querellante(
                    rs.getString("DireccionQ"),
                    rs.getString("NombreQ"),
                    rs.getString("ApellidosQ"),
                    rs.getString("TelefonoQ"),
                    rs.getString("CedulaQ"));
            } else {
                throw new Exception ("Persona no encontrada intentelo de nuevo.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that try-with-resources always closes everything allocated, and in the reverse order of acquisition.

Comment: Looks like getConector() is reusing a singleton connection, yes.